# Do glGenTextures and glGenBuffers share the same name base?

Tags: opengl

Im doing this simple game and decided to manage the buffer and texture ids myself (unsigned ints). The reason doesn't matter much since we are capable of doing so, i have my reasons.

But then this weird question came to mind.
Should i use a different counter for texture and vbo IDs?
Is it valid for a Texture ID and VBO ID to use the same "name" or some sort of collision happens?

Comment: "*since we are capable of doing so*" Well, that rather depends on whether you're using the core OpenGL profile or the compatibility one.

Comment: i just didn't want people to focus on this part of my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only OpenGL objects that share name spaces are shader and program objects. So textures and buffer objects do not share the same name space.